# jquery .change() prevents.click() on other element

Tags: jquery

My html is:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" /><br/>
<a id="a1" href="#">button</a>
```

with javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').change(function() {
        alert('text1Change');
    });
    $('#a1').click(function() {
        alert('link1Click');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/9dvzQ/)

When I enter text in t1, then click link a1 without changing focus or leaving textfield, then only change event is fired.

Is it possible to fire both events or only click?

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: alert() is modal, don't use it for debugging purpose, use `console` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/9dvzQ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an alert on the change handler the click on the `anchor` element is not completed.

If you use a `console.log()` statement for testing those event handlers you can see that both the methods are fired

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').change(function() {
        console.log('text1Change');
    });
    $('#a1').click(function() {
        console.log('link1Click');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/93xc8/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log` instead of `alert` and you will see the result on console -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').change(function() {
        console.log('text1Change');
    });
    $('#a1').click(function() {
        console.log('link1Click');
    });
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/9dvzQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you get any problem with console.log then you can use.

`if (typeof console == "undefined") {
    this.console = {log: function() {}};
}`